# HTTP Error 500 19 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-error, http-status-code-500

Using visual studio 2015.
.Net Network 4.6.1

Everytime I do a pull from source control I cant run the project I get the following error **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.** (please see image)[image]

Comment: 500.19 means there is a problem in the `Web.Config`. Post that and we can take a look.

Comment: You forgot to install an out-of-band IIS module such as URL Rewrite. That's why its error line is 0.